# Add class to div when certain values chosen

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have used angular to show content when choosing values from dropdown.

Now I'm looking for solution to add class to div when values has been chosen. So when choosing certain values from drop down then add certain css class to div.

What is good/correct way to add css class depending on values user has chosen from drop down? For example user choose A, A and Adult (first values from dropdown).

```
<div class="ticketsystem" ng-controller="Main" ng-app>
    <div>selections = {{selections}}</div>

    <div class="choose">
        <p>Choose</p>
        <p>From</p>
        <select ng-model="selections[0]" ng-options="i.id as i.name for i in items">
            <option value=""></option>
        </select>
        <p>To</p>
        <select ng-model="selections[1]" ng-options="i.id as i.name for i in items">
            <option value=""></option>
        </select>
        <p>Group</p>
        <select ng-model="selections[2]" ng-options="i.id as i.name for i in itemsb">
            <option value=""></option>
        </select>
    </div>


    <div class="show-this-3" ng-show="
    selections[0] == items[1].id && selections[1] == items[1].id && selections[2] == itemsb[0].id || 
    selections[0] == items[0].id && selections[1] == items[0].id && selections[2] == itemsb[0].id || 
    selections[0] == items[2].id && selections[1] == items[2].id && selections[2] == itemsb[0].id">
        <p>Tickets</p>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="ticket">Ticket 1</div>
            <div class="ticket">Ticket 2</div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<!-- Add class to this div -->
<div class="add-class">Text</div>
```

Here is [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/agenjn1c/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Use ng-class

```
<div ng-class="{expression}"> ... </div>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Here in your div

```
<div ng-class="{add-class:condition}">Text</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

Formate is like this

```
ng-class="{'className':expression}"
```

**controller**

```
$scope.temp=true
```

**view**

```
<div ng-class="{'myClass':temp}">
```

If temp is true then myClass will be added to your div